# When conducting the double slit experiment, does moving the screen give interference patterns in positions with straight alignment from the slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment

When firing single photons and letting and interference pattern occur. If you were to draw a straight line from one of the slits to a particular interference gap on the screen, and continued this line through the screen, when you moved the screen to different distances from the slits, would an interference gap be present along the lines trajectory at all screen distances? Or would the interference alternative between gap/no gap along the lines trajectory at different screen distances?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off by defining a coordinates system such that $y=0$ runs through the middle of the two slits. Doing so means that the peak of the $0$'th fringe (with maximal brightness) also lies at $y=0$. Using this coordinate system, the angle n'th fringe with maximum brightness is given by
$$
\tan(\theta_n)=n\frac{\lambda}{d}$$
where $d$ is the distance between the two slits. As you can see, if you increase or decrease the distance between the slit and the screen, it wont change the angle of which the fringes appear on the screen. On the other hand, we have from a pure geometrical point of view
$$
\tan(\theta_n)=\frac{y_n}{L},
$$
where $y_n$ is the distance from $y=0$ to the fringe (of maximal brightness) and $L$ is the distance between the slits and screen. However, since $\theta_n$ doesn't change with a change of $L$, $y_n$ must also change.

Finally we arrive at an answer to your question. If you draw a line from the split to a fringe at position $y_n=y_1$ and keep the two endpoints fixed, once you move the splits the interference pattern experienced at $y_1$ (now no longer equal to $y_n$) will alternate between maximal and minimal brightness in a sinusoidal manner.

Note: You specifically asked for a line that starts at one particular slit. This is just a matter of choosing another coordinate system and thus won't have any impact on the physics observed.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. If i understand correctly your calculations are based on the accepted belief that the interference pattern is caused by wave theory. The formulae thus give the results of alternating maximal and minimal brightness at y1. Do you know of any papers or practical data of this experimemt being tried (the moving of the screen to different distances and interference at y1 being recorded), confirming the theory. I am curious as it seems should y1 show no alternation in experiment, it could open the discussion for another possibility other than wave theory....

Comment: I just need to make myself clear - the calculations aren't based on the belief that the patterns are caused by wave theory as much as they are based on emperical facts (this might sound pedantic but it is a very important distinction). People have done the experiment and saw that these equations described what was going on. The fact that this just so happened to fit with wave theory is another story. I am not aware of any papers that tried to vary the screen distance directly, however screen distance various from paper to paper and you could try to compare them in that way.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond.